# Error occurs when trying to return an object in java web services

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish, netbeans-7

Someone please help me in getting past this error that I get. I am a newbie to java web services. I get the error as said below. I am using the GlassFish server and the NetBeans IDE.

```
CalculatorWSApplication a = port.setinfo(name, age);
required: CalculatorWSApplication
found:    CalculatorWSApplication_Type
1 error
```

Here is the Server program

```
package org.me.calculator;

import com.sun.tools.xjc.api.S2JJAXBModel;
import javax.annotation.*;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@WebService(serviceName = "CalculatorWSApplication")
@Stateless()
public class CalculatorWSApplication {
public String firstName;
public String secondName;

    /**
     * Web service operation
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "add")
    public int add(@WebParam(name = "i") int i, @WebParam(name = "j") int j) {
        //TODO write your implementation code here:
        int k = i + j;
        return k;
    }


    @WebMethod(operationName = "setinfo")
    public CalculatorWSApplication setinfo(@WebParam(name = "firstName") String firstName, @WebParam(name = "secondName") String secondName) {
        CalculatorWSApplication a = new CalculatorWSApplication();
        //TODO write your implementation code here:
        System.out.println("Called");
        a.firstName = firstName;
        a.secondName = secondName;
        System.out.println(a.firstName);
        System.out.println(a.secondName);
        return a;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void sayHello(){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void sayBye(){
        System.out.println("Bye");
    }
}
```

Here is the Client program
Contains two web methods.
First one is add which returns am Integer
Second one is setFirstNameandLastName which returns CalculatorWSApplication object.

```
package calculatorws_client_application;

import org.me.calculator.CalculatorWSApplication;

public class CalculatorWS_Client_Application {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        try{
    int i = 3;
    int j = 4;
    int result = add(i, j);
    setFirstNameandLastName("Rajesh","Gubbianna");
    System.out.println("Result = " + result);

        } catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Exception: " + ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static int add(int i, int j) {
        org.me.calculator.CalculatorWSApplication_Service service = new org.me.calculator.CalculatorWSApplication_Service();
        org.me.calculator.CalculatorWSApplication port = service.getCalculatorWSApplicationPort();
        return port.add(i, j);
    }

    private static void setFirstNameandLastName(String name, String age){
        org.me.calculator.CalculatorWSApplication_Service service = new org.me.calculator.CalculatorWSApplication_Service();
        org.me.calculator.CalculatorWSApplication port = service.getCalculatorWSApplicationPort();
        System.out.println(name + " " + age);
        CalculatorWSApplication a = port.setinfo(name, age);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### A valid endpoint implementation class must meet the following requirements:

- It must carry a javax.jws.WebService annotation.
- Any of its methods may carry a javax.jws.WebMethod annotation.
- All of its methods may throw java.rmi.RemoteException in addition to any service-specific exceptions.
- All method parameters and return types must be compatible with the JAXB 2.0 Java to XML Schema mapping definition.
- A method parameter or return value type must not implement the java.rmi.Remote interface either directly or indirectly.

### Java Data Types

---

boolean, byte, double, float, long, int, javax.activation.DataHandler, java.awt.Image, java.lang.Object, java.lang.String etc

for more information and for complete list of data types you can check this link

[Click Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13758/data_types.htm#i231438)